# Rails , rake db:migrate giving error on cloning app from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have fetched 2 my apps(which have been working in other linux enviornments) from github in newly installed linux. I installed , mysql, nodejs also. I created a test application in rails , and have tested it to be working. But the apps i have cloned, are giving error on running rake db:migrate.

**The error in app1**:

rake db:migrate
==  CreateItems: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:items)
   -> 0.0025s
==  CreateItems: migrated (0.0027s) ===========================================

==  AddDataToTableItems: migrating ============================================
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `manufacturer' for #

**The error in app2**

rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Though both the errors are different, they should be related(as the apps are working in other enviornments) . I am stuck due to the issue for half a day . Any inputs regarding the same ?

PS:Migration files for the apps are as follows :
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18367173/migrate_app2.tar.gz
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18367173/migrate_app1.tar.gz

Comment: Can you post the migrations somewhere?

Comment: Uploaded the migration files  :
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18367173/migrate_app1.tar.gz

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18367173/migrate_app2.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to add something in a manufacturer field before creating that table column.

Ensure that first all the real migrations are run (those modifying the schema) and only after, run the ones where you publish data in your db.

By the way, you shouldn't use migrations to publish sample data in your apps, you should use rake tasks for this or database seeds.

Comment: Thanks . i am adding column(manufacturer) in the last migration. But no data has been put before , for manufacturer field. so it should not throw error.

yea,planning to move the sample data to seeds. let me put data in seed and check .

Comment: Also any comments for the second app . All the migrations are independent in it(and no seed data to ) ?

Thanks for help .

Comment: Yes, please put Model.create's inside db/seeds/rb and run them with rake db:seed  Also please use a gui tool or the command line to examine the items table and see what it has.

Comment: I moved to seed data, and it worked .
Thanks :) 
Any comments for second app ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i am using firefox plugin sqllite manager for view table data.